# Centripetal force related problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

If a bike rider constantly keeps rotating on a vertical circular path, what is the required minimum velocity on the highest point of the circle to keep him on the circular path without falling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245568/

Comment: The friction force must be greater or equal to the centrifugal force $\mu\,{m\,g}\geq \dfrac {mv^{2}}{r}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rider is travelling inside the edge of the circle then at minimum velocity the centripetal force maintaining the circular path at the top *is* the weight of the rider. Therefore $$mg = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$ which gives $$v = \sqrt (gr)$$ where $g = 9.81 ms^{-2}$ and $r =$ the radius of the circle.